# Get all combination of items from one list based on another list

Tags: python, list, combinations

What would the most efficient way of getting all 3 item combination of items in list based on another list?
Lets say I have these three lists:

```
 sec_floors= [1, 2, 3],
 assigned_floor= [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
 sector_number= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13],
```

I need to get all the 3 item combos of items from sector `sector_number` list based on coresponding numbers from `assigned_floor`.

In the sec_floors I have list of all the unique numbers from assigned_floor.

So first combination would be:

`(0,2,5)` `(0,2,6)` `(0,2,7)`...

then `(0,3,5)`, `(0,3,6)` etc.

Its based on index of the corresponding numbrs from sector_number to assingned_floor.

EDIT
@Park Answer works properly when I input floors from lowest to highest number but it fails when for example I start with higher in the list:

```
sec_floors = [16,17,18,7,6]
assigned_floor = [16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 7, 7, 7, 7 6, 6, 6]
sector_number =[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

It seems bisect won't work if data is not sorted, however is it possible to keep it unsorted in any way?

Comment: checkout itertools https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/permutation-and-combination-in-python/

Comment: Please clarify your description and example. It's very unclear how `sec_floors` relates to `assigned_floor` and how you arrived at your example combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `assigned_floor` is sorted, how about this?

```
from bisect import bisect_left as bl
from bisect import bisect_right as br
from itertools import product

sec_floors= [1, 2, 3]
assigned_floor= [1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
sector_number= [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]

sectors = [sector_number[bl(assigned_floor, i): br(assigned_floor, i)] for i in sec_floors]

pdts = list(product(*sectors))
print(pdts)
```

The `bisect_left` above is a built-in function for binary search in python. It returns the leftmost index of its matched value.(`bisect_right` returns the next index of the rightmost index its matched value)

But to use this, be sure that the value in the `sec_floors` is in the `assigned_floor`. Even if the value is not in there, it returns the index.(For more info: https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html)

So

1. If the `assigned_floor` is not sorted, sort it first.
2. Make sure that all of sec_floors value is in the `assigned_floor` by using `set` or something else.

Comment: I found out this wont work for unsorted data, so if I start with floor number in different order like [3,3,3,1,1, 2,2] this will fail. Any idea why is this happening?